# How do I export the machine learning (Tensorflow) predictions to a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, tensorflow, data-analysis

I have included my code [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HcqdV8O5dLXDvmSaBfUpN14oWY25TsY3-PmcyO3cytA/edit?usp=sharing) on google docs.

I am not able to export the predicted values which are printed as output to a csv file.

```
for i in range(0, 101):
prediction_run = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: X[i].reshape(1, 60)})
accuracy_run = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: X[i].reshape(1, 60), y_: Y[i].reshape(1, 2)})
print("Original Class : ", y1[i], " Predicted Values : ", prediction_run[0], " Accuracy : ", accuracy_run)
```

Comment: What error do you get while exporting ? That would make the question more clearer

Comment: I am using pandas to export it to csv, and I guess the problem is that the datatypes are not matching.

Comment: Please do not guess the problem, instead include relevant and complete error messages in your question.

Comment: The code I have included in google docs has no errors at all. I am not able to export the results which are printing to csv. What I am looking for is the code segment which could be used to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code you're not using pandas at all to export it to csv. What you can do is to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

prediction_value = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: x_test}
prediction_df = pd.DataFrame(prediction_value)
prediction_df.to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

Btw, next time it would be better to put your code on gist instead in a google drive.